# Fade in Fade-out Animation on RecyclerView Item TextView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a grid items on recyclerView, each item with image and textView overlapping imageView, I applied a fadeinOut animation.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
 />
</set>
```

So when i scroll down the new items not holding the fadeInOut animation
and same when i scroll  up the item entered on view are not holding the animation

Comment: What do you mean they are not holding their animation?

Comment: Yes they are not holding once they are scrolled up and and scrolled back

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying... What is holding supposed to mean?

Comment: You mean the animation stops or gets stuck? Does the animation on the new items stop? Or does it start on the new items?

Comment: Refer https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213 and try to solve your issue. I hope it works!